Allow Symfony Local Web Server to listen to any IP address
Unlike Symfony v4 and below that used WebServerBundle, I cannot find any documentation that would allow me to configure Local Web Server to listen on any IP (vs 127.0.0.1). Is that still possible? I also cannot find any documentation on why the option on local:server:start removed the ability to specify the IP (e.g. 0.0.0.0:8000) vs. only the port.

In theory, the local web server should try listening on any available local IP address. See here: https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/issues/249#issuecomment-1632420403.

This was an intentional change that was thankfully reverted by the Symfony team.
